# locationManager.getLastKnownLocation() always returns null on new xperia X performance

Tags: android, location, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-gps, sony-xperia

I'm creating an app that needs to know the users coarse location and on every other phone I've tested this works fine but on my xperia X performance, `getLastKnownLocation()` always returns null without exception.

This code works on other devices and the gps works on my phone with other apps.

```
  public boolean startLocationManager() {
    // Check for permission to use Fine Location
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mActivity,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mActivity.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            String providerInfo = null;

            // Check if Network provider is enabled
            if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
                providerInfo = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
            }
            else{
                showSettingsAlert();
            }

            // Application can use GPS or Network Provider
            if (providerInfo != null) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        providerInfo,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
                        this
                );

                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                }

                if(location != null){
                    isEnabled = true;
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(mActivity, R.string.location_is_turned_off, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "Can't connect to LocationManager", e);
        }
    }
    return isEnabled;
}
```

I've given the app the right permissions and I still can't get anything but null from `getLastKnownLocation()`.

I don't know if it's of any help but heres some phone info:
[Phone info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEp6R.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (providerInfo != null) {
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
        providerInfo,
        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
        this
    );

if (locationManager != null) {
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(
        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
}
```

It's not guaranteed to get location from  `getLastKnownLocation`, because it retrieves previously cached location if any. You have to wait until `onLocationChanged` callback is fired

Comment: I had the app running for ten minutes while walking around outside and `onLocationChanged()` didn't fire once.

Comment: What about minTime and minDistance parameters ? To make it test try passing 0 for these parameters and wait for `onLocationChanged`. Or, u are facing something like [that](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57707)